# gdb remote cross debugging fails with "Remote 'g' packet reply is too long"

Tags: debugging, qt4, gdb, qt-creator, gdbserver

I have a problem with remote debugging.

Host: laptop intel i5 with ubuntu 10.10 x86 
Target: Freescale iMX35 (iMX35 PDK) arm 11
Development environment: Qt Creator 2.1RC and Qt4.7.1 libraries.
Arm compiler in path: /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin

arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.1.2  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objdump
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-addr2line  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gccbug
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib     arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcov       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-readelf
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-run        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-size       arm-none-linux-gnueabi-c++filt
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gprof      arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strings
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp        arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip      arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm         arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy

The goal is to debug a project created with Qt. 
So I simply created a Qt Quick Project -> Qt Quick Application
which creates a simple Hello World application (C++/Qml)
I cross compile it (in debug or release) and it works fine 
on the target. So I'm quite sure that cross compilation 
is not related to the problem I'll show you.

I downloaded gdb 7.2 and performed the following operation:

> $ export PATH=/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.1.2-glibc-2.5-nptl-3/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
>   $ cd /home/elux/iMX35/gdb-7.2/
>   $ ./configure --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=i686
>   $ make
>   $ sudo make install
>
> $ export CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
>   $ export LD=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
>   $ cd gdb/gdbserver/
>   $ ./configure --build=i386 --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-none-linux-
>   gnueabi
>   $ make
>
> $ sudo cp gdbserver /home/elux/MX35/ltib/rootfs/usr/bin/ (to copy gdbserver to target)

Then on the target:

> $ gdbserver 10.10.10.1:4000 Test
>   Process Test created; pid = 2194
>   Listening on port 4000

On the target:

> $ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gdb Test   (Test is cross-compiled it Qt Creator in debug mode)
>   GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2
>   Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>   This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>   There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
>   and "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "--host=i686 --target=arm-none-linux-gnueabi".
>   For bug reporting instructions, please see:
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/...
>   Reading symbols from /home/elux/iMX35/ltib/rpm/BUILD/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1  /platform/Test-build-arm/Test...done.
>   (gdb) target remote 10.10.10.2:4000
>   Remote debugging using 10.10.10.2:4000
>   **warning: Can not parse XML target description; XML support was disabled at compile time**
>   **warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.**
>   **GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers**
>   **and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.**
>   0x400007e0 in ?? ()
>   (gdb)

and

> (gdb) set solib-absolute-prefix /home/elux/iMX35/ltib/rootfs/
>   Reading symbols from /home/elux/iMX35/ltib/rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.3...done.
>   Loaded symbols for /home/elux/iMX35/ltib/rootfs/lib/ld-linux.so.3

but

> (gdb) set architecture armv5te
>   The target architecture is assumed to be armv5te
>   Remote 'g' packet reply is too long:   00000000a7ee8ebe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b0ed8ebe00000000e007004010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> (gdb) b main
>   Remote 'g' packet reply is too long:   00000000a7ee8ebe0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b0ed8ebe00000000e007004010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Have you got any idea what this problem is related to? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 23):

I was able to use gdb-multiarch instead and resolved my issue.

Comment: Also, check to make sure the `gdb-multiarch` package is up to date.

Comment: Worked also in my case of trying to debug with the Valdrind built-in vgdb server. Trying to use the native ARM gdb on device gave the same "Remote 'g' packet too long" error. But running vgdb on TCP port and connecting to it from host with gdb-multiarch worked!

Answer (score 19):

As I ran into this recently on Ubuntu 12.04 (x86_64) and solved it in a different way, I thought I'd comment. The kicker in this case is that Ubuntu seems to have gdb with libexpat enabled. Some tinkering later and this solved it for me:

> set architecture i386:x86-64:intel

So it appears this can result when there is a mismatch of architectures as well.

Comment: Don't know about the OP but that fixed my problem. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If the problem persists after setting the architecture, it might be a register-size-switching problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34304137/151464

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem trying to debug a Freescale ARM on an i5 machine running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit.

The fix that worked for me was to specify the *--with-expat* flag when configuring gdb. I also had to install the *libexpat1-dev* package.

[Explanation here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gdb.devel/29306)