# Question mark symbols in gdb while debugging linux kernel 4.10

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug the linux kernel right from the function start_kernel() in the linux kernel.

This is basically what I ve done

Downloaded the kernel source for 4.10 from kernel.org
After extracting the source:

> > make menuconfig : Changed the settings for kernel debugging
> >
> > make -j4: compiled the kernel

Simply issued the command without any FS

> qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux-4.10/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append root=/dev/zero -s -S
>   The qemu stoped as it should:

Next in another terminal, i started gdb

> gdb vmlinux : and the output is as follows
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> Reading symbols from vmlinux...done.
>
> (gdb) target remote :1234
>   Remote debugging using :1234
>   0x0000fff0 in ??()
>   (gdb) list

```
1   /*
2    *
3    *  Copyright (C) 1991, 1992  Linus Torvalds
4    *
5    *  Enhanced CPU detection and feature setting code by Mike Jagdis
6    *  and Martin Mares, November 1997.
7    */
8   
9   .text
10  #include <linux/threads.h>
```

That means debug symbols are there.
Now when i use the command

> (gdb) b start_kernel
>
> Breakpoint 1 at 0xc1ba986e: file init/main.c, line 483.

And I hit c (continue), it doesn't hit the breakpoint.

What wrong am I doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use hardware breakpoints instead of software breakpoints.

You can use `hbreak` to insert hardware breakpoints. `hbreak` and `break` have similar usages. Moreover, you can use `help hbreak` to show more information.

I guess that the reason why software breakpoints are not effective is that the `INT3` instruction inserted by software breakpoints is covered when the kernel image is loaded after you continue the QEMU.

But some troubles will occur because the processor mode changes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662468/remote-g-packet-reply-is-too-long) gives some useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA and CONFIG_RANDOMIZE_BASE.